Blender 4.3 How to make Gore fluid sim create strands between objects
I'm trying to make a fluid simulation for gore that would create strands between two objects being pulled apart, however, i cant seem to get the result im looking for. not only is the fluid not "Sticking" to the objects as much as i would like (and when i increase the Viscosity it just moves slower), but i also would like to have the liquid appear like its coming out of the objects being pulled apart, but not be emitted by the entire mesh. How would i go about doing this?
What i want
What i get

Could you add pictures to show what you have achieved, and to illustrate the defaults you are describing ? Could you also share your Blender file as a starting point to work an answer using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

@StefLAncien here is the blender file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q2rlSuQGyF4XVKFWL5UQ6hETYFRs2Ohs/view?usp=sharing
